# Can I create an in-memory index of a SQLite database with the actual database file being on disk

Tags: sqlite, memory, indexing

To reduce filesize of a database, I would like to create (if this is possible) - the indexes of a file-based database from SQLite, in memory.

i.e.
Database file ABC.db3
but create an index on various fields in ABC.db3, into an in-memory database WITHOUT having to copy the contents of the ABC.db3 file-based database into memory, but getting the performance (or even better because the indexes are memory-based) as when performing searches on the file-based ABC.db3 ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with built-in indexes.

You would have to do the indexing manually, i.e., something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE disk.Tab (
    ID   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Name TEXT,
    [...]
);

CREATE TABLE memdb.IndexOnTab (
    Name TEXT,
    ID   INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (Name, ID)
) WITHOUT ROWID; -- clustered index

INSERT INTO IndexOnTab SELECT Name, ID FROM Tab;

-- instead of SELECT * FROM Tab WHERE Name = ?
SELECT *
FROM Tab
WHERE ID = (SELECT ID
            FROM IndexOnTab
            WHERE Name = ?);
```

It might be possible to hide this in a [virtual table](http://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html), but that is probably not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the existing database to a database opened with ":memory:" as a filepath. Then you can add indexes to that database.